# "Use of unresolved identifier" error only appear when Build Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to Archive IPA from my Swift project and I have a "Framework Project" that's referenced to main project. It's working fine when build and run normally. But when I try to "Archive", it encountered error "Use of unresolved identifier..." for my all of classes that are defined in the framework project.

[image]

Comment: Restart your Xcode and try again.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni  I restarted Xcode serveral times before I post the question here. The problem stills there!

Comment: What are those defined as? Also, try doing a clean build (**`Shift` + `Command` + `K`**)

Comment: @Jojodmo SEUser and SessionDTORequest are defined in Swift_Backend_Lib framework project. As you can see they still have green color. I clean build folder(Shift + Option + Command + K) every time before I wanna Build Archive also

Comment: This happens when you build for a target that the framework is not capable of building for. Can be architecture or OS version. For example: the framework is 9.2 and up and the project is 8.0 and up.

Comment: @RMenke It's the same version since I've created the projects

Comment: And the build targets? Sim? Device? Generic?

Comment: @RMenke Yes all of them

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and thought I'd post this consideration for those who are scratching their heads.  It may or may not help...

If your code is referencing something that is wrapped in debug macros, it will compile in Xcode and present as fine until you attempt to archive.  Then it will helpfully just not find the reference.

I encountered the compile message:

`use of unresolved identifier 'sampleStore'`

The offending code looked something like this:

```
struct FriendsListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FriendsListView(id: 0).environmentObject(sampleStore)
    }
}
```

This fragment of code looked exactly like several other places that used the same sampleStore.  This threw me off the trail.

It took some time to realize that the definition of `sampleStore` was wrapped in

```
#if DEBUG
let sampleStore = Store()
// etc
#endif
```

So the solution was to also wrap the swiftui preview code in the debug macro

```
#if DEBUG
struct FriendsListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FriendsListView(id: 0).environmentObject(sampleStore)
    }
}
#endif
```